# SQLite errorcode: sqlite_step() returns 5 (SQLITE_BUSY)

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am working on a school project which involves SQLite3.
I've created a bunch of functions for my `DatabaseManager` class which all work quite good.

Now, after adding a function with a **DELETE** statement, `sqlite3_step()` returns `SQLITE_BUSY` and the `sqlite3_errmsg()` says *"Database is locked"*.

Before opening this function I have already called `sqlite3_finalize()` and `sqlite3_close()`.

```
int errorcode;

sqlite3 *db;

//sql statement
std::string statement = "DELETE FROM tbl_follower WHERE flw_ID = " + std::to_string(row);

sqlite3_stmt *binStatement;

errorcode = sqlite3_open(m_filePath.c_str(), &db);

if (errorcode != SQLITE_OK)
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << std::endl;

errorcode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, statement.c_str(), statement.size(), &binStatement, NULL);

if(errorcode != SQLITE_OK)
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << std::endl;

errorcode = sqlite3_step(binStatement);

if (errorcode == SQLITE_DONE)
{
    sqlite3_finalize(binStatement);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
else
{
    //error
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << std::endl;
    sqlite3_finalize(binStatement);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

I am pretty sure the issue is somewhere in this code because I have already checked all of my other functions for mistakes (which all work without giving an error). My SQL statement is also correct.

Comment: What's the actual question? Be specific.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Why is my database locked?

Comment: Edit your question please.

Comment: You could/should try using [`sqlite3_exec`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) instead, which wraps up `finalize` `step and `prepare` and means you can't muck up the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Database is locked" means that there is some other active transaction.

You probably forgot to finalize a statement in some other part of the program.